# Remove Seperator ListView View cells Xamarin.Forms

Tags: listview, xamarin.forms, uitableview

I have a `ListView` in my project using Xamarin.Forms. Iam using `ViewCells`to display the data.

Right now, There is a seperator line showing between two ViewCells. There a way I can remove it so that two ViewCells are always touching each other.

I tried using `SeperatorVisibility="None"`, but it made no difference.

Here is my code:

```
 <ListView x:Name="AList"
                StyleId="AList"
                      Grid.Row="0"
                RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width}"
                RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Height}"
                      IsVisible="{Binding IsProcessing, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource booleanNegationConverter}}"
                SeparatorVisibility="None">
        <ListView.BackgroundColor>
          <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Color" iOS="Transparent" />
        </ListView.BackgroundColor>

        <ListView.RowHeight>
          <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:Int32" iOS="150" Android="150" WinPhone="170" />
        </ListView.RowHeight>
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell > .......</ViewCell></ListView>
```

Comment: You can also write your own CustomRenderer for ListView such as SeperatorlessListView.
For iOS you can take a look at this: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/74497/
Good Luck :)

Answer (score 14):

SeperatorVisibility="None" usually does it for me.

Are you seeing this on all platforms?

Does your view cell contain anything that might be causing it?  Try switching to a standard TextCell and see if you get the seperator.

Comment: I also had the same issue with SeperatorVisibility not working. After re-building the project multiple times it finally removed the line separators, just FYI for anyone struggling.  bug possibly??

Comment: You have a typo in your correct answer: it is : SeparatorVisibility="None"

Answer (score 2):

> Use SeparatorColor attribute in ListView

```
<ListView SeparatorColor="Transparent">
</ListView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
Footer=""
```

to your ListView XAML tag

Answer (score 0):

Xamarin 4.6.0.847, property: SeparatorVisibility

```
<StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" BackgroundColor="White">
    <ListView x:Name="ListViewMenu"
              HasUnevenRows="False"
              SeparatorVisibility="None">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <StackLayout>
                        <Grid Padding="10" BackgroundColor="White">
                            <Label Text="{Binding Title}" FontSize="20"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </StackLayout>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</StackLayout>
```